# How to set the leaseTimeout setting programmaticaly?

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

We have a WCF service (`NetTcpBinding`) that sits behind a load balancer. [I've read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128.aspx) that in order to avoid  "stickyniss" I have lower the `LeaseTime` the channels get in the channel pool.

I've only found samples how to set this value using the config file, but I would like to set it programmaticaly, any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the `LeaseTimeout` property via the `TcpTransportBindingElement`, through the `ConnectionPoolSettings` property:

```
TcpTransportBindingElement tcpBE = new TcpTransportBindingElement();
tcpBE.ConnectionPoolSettings.LeaseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
```

If you have a `NetTcpBinding` object, you'll need to first convert it into a `CustomBinding`, then access the binding element. The example below shows one way of doing this.

```
NetTcpBinding myOriginalBinding = CreateBinding();
CustomBinding newBinding = new CustomBinding(myOriginalBinding);
TcpTransportBindingElement tcpBE = newBinding.Elements.Find<TcpTransportBindingElement>();
tcpBE.ConnectionPoolSettings.LeaseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
```

Comment: And this would apply the settings app-wide? I don't have to attach this class to my binding/channel etc?

Comment: You'll need to convert the `netTcpBinding` to a custom binding, then access the `TcpTransportBindingElement` directly. I've updated the answer with more information.