# Disable connection pooling for WCF net.tcp bindings

Tags: wcf, net.tcp

I have a specific scenario where I need to disable net.tcp connection pooling. I realize it's not an ideal configuration, however I need to do it temporarily to troubleshot issues in my specific environment.

Can anyone provide an example of a net.tcp binding configuration that disables the connection reuse\pooling?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it, in code.

```
NetTcpBinding tbinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, true);

// set some stuff on the binding ...
// ...

BindingElementCollection bElementCol = tbinding.CreateBindingElements();

TcpTransportBindingElement transport = bElementCol.Find<TcpTransportBindingElement>();
transport.ConnectionPoolSettings.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero;
transport.ConnectionPoolSettings.LeaseTimeout =  TimeSpan.Zero;
transport.ConnectionPoolSettings.MaxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint = 0;

CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding();
customBinding.Elements.AddRange(bElementCol.ToArray());
customBinding.Name = "NetTcpBinding";
// use customBinding instead of tbinding
```

Here's some links that helped me with that:

[How to set the leaseTimeout setting programmaticaly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388179/how-to-set-the-leasetimeout-setting-programmaticaly)

http://plainoldstan.blogspot.ca/2007/09/nettcpbinding-to-custombinding.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788984.aspx